# How to pass arrays to a subroutine and then to call it in Fortran77?

Tags: arrays, fortran, call, subroutine, fortran77

I want to manipulate a large code. I want to calculate rmse of the result calculated in the main program. I have added following subroutine to calculate rmse

```
subroutine rmse(A,B,nmax,rmseans)
      Integer nmax
      Double Precision A(nmax),B(nmax),C(nmax),d(nmax)
      Real e,f,rmseans
      COMMON /PAR7/ XTIME,STAGE,RECH,OBS 
      e = 0
      do 103 i=1,nmax
          c(i)= (a(i)-b(i))
          d(i)= (c(i))**2
          e = e+d(i)
103  enddo
      rmseans = sqrt(e/nmax)
      End`
```

It takes two arrays A and B and gives rmse as `rmseans` while `nmax` is total number of terms. 
Then I am calling at end of main program this subroutine as

```
Call rmse(OBS,H,NT,rmseans)
Write(*,*) rmseans
```

But this is giving me quite wrong answer. I have made sure that values OBS,and H are calculated before calling the subroutine by writing these two values in a file.

Comment: Why does it have to be F77?

Comment: You don't show how the arguments that you call `rmse` call with are defined, but you are mixing `Real` and `Double Precision`. Your vectors are double precision, the result is real. make sure that the parameter types match. Better yet, use one consistent precision throughout.

Comment: @haraldkl It isn't Fortran 77, it's (at least) Fortran 90 - it uses automatic arrays. Lord knows why, it doesn't need them, but it does.

Comment: Show your result and your code. Explain which resukt do you expect. Make a minimal example, as small as possible but still complete.

Comment: @MOehm   Thankyou very much. Changed `e,f,rmseans` in subroutine to `Double Precision` and the answer is correct now.

Comment: c and d do not need to be arrays.

Comment: And you don't even need d: `e = e + c*c`

Comment: Also, note that this is a naïve approach to the problem that doesn't account for the possibilities of overflow. And what's that COMMON block doing there?